# Travelling from London to USA with a US tourist visa issued in the Philippines

Tags: usa, planning, filipino-citizens

I am a filipino with  a US tourist visa. If I come to London first, can I go to US from there?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  The answer is yes.  Why would there be a concern?

Comment: Are you asking if going via London would be a problem for the US visa, or if the US visa somehow changes your visa requirements to visit the UK?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. The US will not care at all from where you enter the country.

While some countries issue certain visas that may require you to enter a country on a certain border crossing or coming from a certain country, this is not very common and will certainly be stated on the visa.
If it does not say anything about this, there are no restrictions.

Comment: Can you provide further explanation, some references perhaps?

Comment: Since the visa does NOT state from where you have to enter the country from, you can enter from where ever you want. Since this is the absence of a rule, there is no official reference for it. Also, your example has nothing do to with this case. Re-entering is not possible because the visa is single-entry. You can still enter from where you want, but only one single time.

Comment: Also - YOU run hitchwiki.org?? My congrats (and thanks) to you, great site!

Comment: You are right. I elaborated my answer a bit more. And yes, I run hitchwiki. Not alone though, but anyway, thanks :)